# Synchronously load a dependency in node.js

Tags: node.js, require, dependency-management

I'm loading a node library in script and immediately after loading some customization that depends on that library:

```
var somelib = require('somelib');

// some customizations made to
// somelib's methods
require('./somelib.custom');

somelib.SomeObject = ...
^
ReferenceError: somelib is not defined
```

I keep getting an exception since the loading is done asynchronously and the second `require` happens before the first is namespaced correctly. What's a good way to resolve this? thanks.

#### EDIT: My original code

I'm trying to create a PNG image from json data using [`fabric.js`](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) node package (building on the [article](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4/#node) in package site). This is done by loading the server-side fabric canvas with JSON data that was originally generated on the client, then writing to a file stream:

```
var path     = require('path');
var fs       = require('fs');
var fabric   = require('fabric').fabric;
require('./fabric.custom');

var canvas   = fabric.createCanvasForNode(400, 400);
var outfile  = fs.createWriteStream("image.png");
var filepath = "/path/to/file.json";

fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf8', function(err, json) {
  canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {
    var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
    stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
      outfile.write(chunk);
    });
  });
});
```

The "fabric.custom" file holds several custom fabric canvas objects that override some fabric prototype defaults. They work well on the client, and are needed to properly render the canvas. It looks something like this:

```
fabric.TextBox = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Text, {

  type: 'text-box',
  // more object specific stuff ...
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Node's `require` method _is_ synchronous, so I'm not sure what's happening in your case.

Comment: somelib is a package ?? Please put your original code so that we can help.

Comment: Yeah, somelib is actually `fabric.js`, an npm package - I was trying to avoid specifics to make things simpler. See my edits above.

Comment: you can change `stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
      outfile.write(chunk);
    });` to `stream.pipe(outfile);`

Answer (score 5):

Rather than relying on side effects in a `require` to mutate your `fabric` object, how about having the `fabric.custom.js` file export the modified `fabric`, like so?

fabric.custom.js:

```
var fabric = require('fabric').fabric;
fabric.myCustomMethod = function(){ ... }
...
module.exports = fabric; // the modified fabric
```

And in your main file:

```
var path     = require('path');
var fs       = require('fs');
// var fabric   = require('fabric').fabric; No need for this line anymore
var modifiedFabric = require('./fabric.custom');

...
modifiedFabric.myCustomMethod( ... ); // should now be available
```